# Windows 8.1 ComboBox wrap Item text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a really long string which does not feed in one line of the ComboBox item.

How can i make it Wrap the items' text?

I tried this but does not work in Windows 8.1 unviseral App

This is my comboBox

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="ChildrenAgePickerComboBox_0"  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxWrappable}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenAgeOptions}"  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" />
```

This is the style i want to apply in order to Wrap Text

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxWrappable"  TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxBase}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The result is that my combobox has no text at all, and no items are display when i open it.

What is wrong with the DataTemplate? It does not render the items.
It does render them if i don't use the DataTemplate.

Comment: You could set `MaxWidth` either against `TextBlock` or `ComboBoxItem`

Comment: What do you mean? The width is hiding the content? I believe the Binding does not work.

Comment: Did you try something like this `<TextBlock MaxWidth="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>` and what do you mean by _I believe the Binding does not work_? If you see text then it works

Comment: The text does not appear. I Will try this maxWidth alternative.

Comment: So the problem is that text is long but does not wrap or text does not appear at all? If the text does not appear then there is something wrong with `DataContext` or `ItemsSource`

Comment: I edited the question please check

Comment: Did you try removing `DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"` and do `Text="{Binding DisplayText}` instead?

Comment: That was the answer! Please post it and i will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Does it need `MaxWidth` or not? I see you've used `MinWidth` which would suggest it's not required and text is wrapped even without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up comments you don't see your text because you cannot use both `DisplayMemberPath` and `ItemTemplate`. What you should do is remove `DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"` from `ComboBox` and move it into `Text` binding

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxWrappable" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxBase}">
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```